# Can I apply a pattern of getting values' type of object to non-static member of class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I often use this pattern.

```
const numbers = { a: 1 as 1, b: 2 as 2 },
      number: typeof numbers[keyof typeof numbers] = 1; // type of number is (1 | 2)
```

But I couldn't apply that to a class, so I questioned.

```
class Class {
    numbers = { a: 1 as 1, b: 2 as 2 };

    method () {
        const number: this['numbers'][keyof this['numbers']] = 1, // Error: Type '1' is not assignable to type 'this["numbers"][keyof this["numbers"]]'.
              number2: typeof this['numbers'][keyof typeof this['numbers']] = 1; // Error: Cannot find name 'this'. 
    }
}
```

Do you happen to know how to do that? please let me know. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) isn't really what you want to use.  It's possible, for example, for a subclass of `Class` to narrow the type of `numbers`, and then `this['numbers']` would not necessarily have a property with a type of `1`:

```
class Whoops extends Class {
  numbers = {a: null! as never, b: 2 as 2, c: 3 as 3}
}
```

Instead of using the `this` type, just name the class explicitly:

```
const number: Class['numbers'][keyof Class['numbers']] = 1; // okay
```

Also, because that pattern `BlahBlahBlah[keyof BlahBlahBlah]` is redundant and used a lot, I tend to give it a type alias:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

And then you could change the above `number` type annotation to:

```
const number: ValueOf<Class['numbers']> = 1; // okay
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It helped :D